# Meu Form não envia

Tags: php, html

Fiz um formulário para enviar dados de contato (nome, email, assunto e mensagem).

```
<form name="contactForm" id="form-contato" method="post">
                <fieldset>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactName" type="text" id="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Seu nome" value="" minlength="2" maxlength="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" value="" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width" required="required" type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto" value="" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <textarea name="contactMessage" id="Mensagem" name="Mensagem" placeholder="Sua mensagem" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input class="full-width btn--primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                    <div class="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader">Enviando...</div>
                        <div class="s-loader">
                            <div class="bounce1"></div>
                            <div class="bounce2"></div>
                            <div class="bounce3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
</form>

            <!-- contact-warning -->
            <div class="message-warning">
                Ops, aconteceu algum problema, atualize a página e tente novamente, obrigado!
            </div> 

            <!-- contact-success -->
            <div class="message-success">
                Mensagem enviada com sucesso, obrigado!<br>
            </div>
```

Estou utilizando um script *PHP* (`send_email`), mas não consigo disparar o envio dos dados do formulário.
Meu script foi inserido antes do fechamento da tag

```
<script>
            // Variable to hold request
            var request;

            // Bind to the submit event of our form
            $("#form-contato").submit(function(event){

                // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
                event.preventDefault();

                // Abort any pending request
                if (request) {
                    request.abort();
                }
                // setup some local variables
                var $form = $(this);

                // Let's select and cache all the fields
                var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

                // Serialize the data in the form
                var serializedData = $form.serialize();

                // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
                // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
                // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
                $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

                // Fire off the request to /form.php
                request = $.ajax({
                    url: "send_email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData,
                    dataType: "json"
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on success
                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    // Log a message to the console
                    console.log("Hooray, it worked!", response);
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on failure
                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // Log the error to the console
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called regardless
                // if the request failed or succeeded
                request.always(function () {
                    // Reenable the inputs
                    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                });

            });
</script>
```

Esse é o erro gerado no console:

[image: Console Error - jquery]

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você não definiu o atributo `action` do `form`, sendo assim o HTML está sendo enviado para a própria página, se não for esse o problema esclareça melhor sua dúvida

Comment: Talvez esteja faltando o action apontando para a página no form e o method, também no form com o tipo de envio. Se possível, coloque o script em PHP para podermos ajudar de uma melhor forma.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que é possível ver, você esta usando um disparo de evento com jquery, caso seja isso, irei postar um código que sempre funciona comigo, sem problemas;

```
    <form name="contactForm" id="form-contato" method="post">
            <fieldset>

            <div class="form-field">
                <input name="contactName" type="text" id="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Seu nome" value="" minlength="2" maxlength="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" value="" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width" required="required" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto" value="" class="full-width">
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <textarea name="contactMessage" id="Mensagem" name="Mensagem" placeholder="Sua mensagem" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <input class="btn-action full-width btn--primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                <div class="submit-loader">
                    <div class="text-loader">Enviando...</div>
                    <div class="s-loader">
                        <div class="bounce1"></div>
                        <div class="bounce2"></div>
                        <div class="bounce3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

( Apenas adicionei uma classe no botão para ser ouvido pelo JS )

```
<input class="btn-action full-width btn--primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Quem "ativa" o form será assim o Ajax, logo o código será assim:

```
 function callAjax() {

    let data = $('#form-contato').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send_mail.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json', //Você pode alterar aqui pra outros retornos desejados
        beforeSend: function () {

            $('.submit-loader').show();

        },
        success: function (data) {

            //Seu código aqui

            $('.submit-loader').hide();
            return false; 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // Para ver se deu algum erro
            $('.submit-loader').hide();
        }
    })
}

    let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-action')[0];
    btn.addEventListener('click', callAjax);
```

Comment: Mas onde e eu coloco esse callAjax?

Comment: Vou editar com o meu código mais detalhado.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, esse é o modo em que está o meu formulário e abaixo o script que chama a função...

Comment: Na ultima linha, amigo, está assim: btn.addEventListener('click', callAjax); é isso que vai chamar seu callAjax

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância mas eu devo adicionar a function callAjax() abaixo do form ou no final da página?

Comment: Não existe ignorância, você está aprendendo. você pode por no final da pagina, depois de chamar o arquivo Javascript que contém a função, ou pode por no próprio arquivo Javascript. Só pra você entender o que acontece ali; o let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-action')[0]; você está "pegando" o botão. O btn.addEventListener('click', callAjax); você está dizendo "Quando alguém clicar nele, ative a função callAjax". Ou seja, precisa dessas duas linhas, se quiser pode retirar a função e apenas colocar com $('.btn-action').on('click', function(){ // poem tudo o que precisa aqui dentro.})

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo problema, coloquei a function call ajax antes de fechar meu <script>, mas nada...

Comment: Acredito que talvez possa ter algum problema nas minhas classes que fazem o cadastro no banco, ou as que fazem o disparo do email de fato... mas acho que o melhor é eu refazer tudo mesmo e me guiar com outra documentação...

Comment: Agora eu reparei, percebeu que você está usando o atributo NAME duas vezes em cada input, você só pode usar uma vez por input: <input name="contactName" type="text" id="Nome" name="Nome" placeholder="Seu nome" value="" minlength="2" maxlength="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">, retire de todos e deixe apenas 1 NAME por INPUT

Comment: corrigi os dois names, mas ainda nada...

Comment: Refaça o formulário, com cautela, tem muita coisa duplicada, o TYPE também está! Esse erro parece ser que você enviando JSON mas na verdade tem HTML no conteudo, dai da problema